# In CSS flip,TransformZ elements not on top

Tags: css, css-transforms, perspective

I have the following snippet to illustrate this issue.

According to everything I have read, elements positioned using transformZ should be on top as they are 'closer.'  I can't position the active/flipped card 'on top' using z-index because flickering occurs during the transition.  Yet the elements are positioned in the default order of the browser, which means the later elements are on top.  Transform-style and perspective are both applied to the parents.

Why aren't the closer elements on top?

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%; height: 12rem;
  float: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 30rem;
}
.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front { 
  background-color: #66ccff; 
}
.back { 
  background-color: #dd8800; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card:hover .front{ transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.card:hover .back { transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(5em);}

.card2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%; height: 12rem;
  perspective: 30rem;
  float: left;
}
.front2, .back2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front2 { 
  background-color: #66ccff; 
}
.back2 { 
  background-color: #dd8800; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 99;
}
.card2:hover .front2 { transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.card2:hover .back2 { transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(5em);} 

.card3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%; height: 12rem;
  perspective: 30rem;
  float: left;
}
.front3, .back3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front3 { 
  background-color: #66ccff; 
}
.back3 { 
  background-color: #dd8800; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 99;
}
.card3:hover .front3 { transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.card3:hover .back3 { transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(5em);}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card2">
  <div class="front2">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back2">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="card3">
  <div class="front3">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back3">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the use of `persepctive` create a stacking context

> Using this property with a value different than 0 and none creates a new stacking context. Also, in that case, the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements that it contains.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)</sup>

So what you said is all true but it happens inside the card element then the card elements are positionned considering the tree order.

An easy fix is to adjust `z-index` of card element considering some delay to avoid the bad effect.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%; height: 12rem;
  float: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 30rem;
  z-index:0;
  transition:z-index 0s .5s;
}
.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front { 
  background-color: #66ccff; 
}
.back { 
  background-color: #dd8800; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card:hover .front{ transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.card:hover .back { transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(5em);}

.card:hover {
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">         
    <span>Front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Wow.  Yes, this is indeed the issue and a great solution -- I never thought of delaying the z-index.  Thanks for the explanation & reference!